# Options for copying very large directories

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I need to create multiple copies of a 20gb directory.  That directory is not included in my cookbook, but is currently zipped up on a network resource (this can be changed).  I am not including it in the cookbook, because I don't want my chef to be that big.

What I'm currently attempting to do is to use `seven_zip_archive` to copy the directory to a local temp directory, and then use a short `powershell_script` to copy it locally.

This seems, to this beginner, pretty kludgey, and it makes me wonder if there's a better way to do this.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, from where you get it with `seven_zip_archive`, but retrieving it from an external source (HTTP, file mounts etc.) instead of from the Chef Server is the absolutely right way.

Comment: What about copying directories around?  Is there a more 'chef'ey way to do this besides writing a short script?

Comment: There's no way to copy files using a chef resource (only using a `ruby_block` or `execute` and run a shell script). If you can, use `remote_file`). But as long as your approach works well (and is maybe guarded by `creates` or `not_if` then I don't see the need the change anything). Otherwise, share a bit more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `poise_archive` resource can handle the download and caching for you, though I'm not sure I would want to run 20GB of stuff through RubyZip. Otherwise what you have sounds fine.